# How to pad strings to a fixed width with NSMutableString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to write a string to a text file.  That text file will then be read by another program.  That second program is expecting the different "fields" in the text file to be a fixed width.  Therefore, when I write the text file with my app, I will need to add spaces between my actual data to get everything to line up correctly.  How do I get these spaces added?

---

So far, I've tried writing a function that takes a source string and a target length as input. If the target is longer than the source, it just appends " ". Code for this routine is below:

```
- (NSString *) makeStringFrom:(NSString *)source withLength:(NSInteger)length
{
    // Method to add spaces to the end of a string to get it to a certain length
    if ([source length] > length)
    {
        // String is too long - throw warning and send it back
        NSLog(@"Warning - string is already longer than length supplied.  Returning source string");
        return source;
    }
    else if ([source length] == length)
    {
        // String is already correct length, so just send it back
        return source;
    }
    else
    {
        // String is too short, need to add spaces
        NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:source];
        NSLog(@"newString initial length = %d",[newString length]);
        for (int current = [source length]; current < length; current ++)
        {
            [newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
            NSLog(@"hit");
        }

        NSLog(@"target length = %d.  newString length = %d",length,[newString length]);
        return newString;
    }
}
```

This apparently doesn't work. The length of the string I'm getting back in the return isn't changing any from the length of the supplied string, even when the NSLog(@"hit"); runs multiple times.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {[string appendString:@" "];}`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: That's what I tried (see my answer below).  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: No you didn't do same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [`stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByPaddingToLength%3awithString%3astartingAtIndex%3a) method on `NSString` that does just this.

Comment: Thanks, this actually looks like the best way to go. No sense in me writing my own code when there is something already built-in to do it.

Comment: And this one is probably more optimized than a for-loop that could add a hundred thousand spaces, one by one, in the same runloop without releasing anything until the end of the runloop...

Answer (score 1):

You did a silly mistake here

```
 [newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

This **returns a new string, and it doesnot effect the caller object**. You need to store it

```
newString=[newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

or simply

```
[newString appendString:@" "];
```

Comment: Since `newString` is mutable, you should only use the last form.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change:

```
[newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

into:

```
newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```